# KornShell Sort Array of Integers

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, scripting, ksh

Is there a command in KornShell (ksh) scripting to sort an array of integers?  In this specific case, I am interested in simplicity over efficiency.  For example if the variable $UNSORTED_ARR contained values "100911, 111228, 090822" and I wanted to store the result in $SORTED_ARR

Comment: Latest answer for the same. As the current answer didn't work for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900170/how-to-sort-integer-array-in-ksh-unix-shell-scripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it actually an indexed array or a list in a string?

Array:

```
UNSORTED_ARR=(100911 111228 090822)
SORTED_ARR=($(printf "%s\n" ${UNSORTED_ARR[@]} | sort -n))
```

String:

```
UNSORTED_ARR="100911, 111228, 090822"
SORTED_ARR=$(IFS=, printf "%s\n" ${UNSORTED_ARR[@]} | sort -n | sed ':a;$s/\n/,/g;N;ba')
```

There are several other ways to do this, but the principle is the same.

Here's another way for a string using a different technique:

```
set -s -- ${UNSORTED_ARR//,}
SORTED_ARR=$@
SORTED_ARR=${SORTED_ARR// /, }
```

Note that this is a *lexicographic* sort so you would see this kind of thing when the numbers don't have leading zeros:

```
$ set -s -- 10 2 1 100 20
$ echo $@
1 10 100 2 20
```

Comment: It's an indexed array of strings.. so I believe the first example.  The only problem is that I get an "Unexpected (" for the (first version) SORTED_ARR assignment.  If I take that out then it works but I can't loop through it (because its a list of strings now)

Comment: Got it!  Cheated with:
set -A SORTED_ARR $(printf "%s\n" ${UNSORTED_ARR[@]} | sort -n)

Answer (score 0):

> *If I take that out then it works but I can't loop through it (because its a list of strings now) – pws5068 Mar 4 '11 at 21:01*

Do this:

```
\# create sorted array
set **-s** -A $@
```