# KSH sort filenames

Tags: unix, sorting, ksh, sh

I'm searching through a number of directories for "searchstring", and then running a script on each $file:

```
for file in `find $dir -name ${searchstring}'*'`;
do
    echo $file >> $debug
    script.sh $file >> $output
done
```

My $debug file yields the following:

> /root/0007_searchstring/out/filename_20120105_020000.log
>   /root/0006_searchstring/out/filename_20120105_010000.log
>   /root/0005_searchstring/out/filename_20120105_013000.log
>   (filename is _yyyymmdd_hhmmss.log)
>   ...

Is there a way to get find to order by filename or by mktime? Should I pipe find to sort first? Make an array then sort it as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198283/ksh-sort-array-of-integers)?

Comment: `|sort -n` seems pretty reasonable to me -- provided your `sort` implementation supports `-n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore the directory path and just use the file name, then you should be able to use:

```
for file in `find $dir -name ${searchstring}'*' | sort --field-separator=/ --key=4`;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know sort could do this. I ended up using `sort -t/ -k 4`

Answer (score 1):

'ls -t' if you need to regenerate the list based on timestamp.

'sort -n' if the list is fairly static?

Answer (score 1):

To sort by modification time, you can use stat with find:

```
$ find . -exec stat {} -c '%Y %n' \; | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of find through sort to sort by filename:

```
find $dir -name "${searchstring}*" | sort | while read file
do
    echo "$file" >> $debug
    script.sh "$file" >> $output    
done
```